# TTreeView: How to change the text of item's inplace editor?

Tags: delphi, treeview, editor, delphi-xe, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView with editable items. When I press F2 or click any item after selection, the inplace editor appearing.

How can I change the text which is displayed in that editor before showing it? For example, my tree item's text is `Point 1 (300, 450)`, but I want my inplace editor to display only `Point 1`.

I tried to catch `OnEditing` event like that:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeViewEditing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode; 
  var AllowEdit: Boolean);
begin
  AllowEdit := True;
  Node.Text := 'text to edit';
end;
```

However, the text of inplace editor isn't changing, the tree item's text updated only after cancelling edit. How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try if the following suits you:

```
uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Editing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode; var AllowEdit: Boolean);
var
  EditHandle: THandle;
  S: string;
begin
  AllowEdit := True;
  S := 'text to edit';
  EditHandle := TreeView_GetEditControl((Sender as TTreeView).Handle);
  SendMessage(EditHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LParam(PChar(S)));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Came here looking for a solution to the same problem but in C++. Ondrej Kelle's answer translated in C++ is like this:

```
TTreeView* tree;
std::string str;
HWND EditHandle = TreeView_GetEditControl(tree->Handle);
::SendMessage(EditHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(str.c_str()));
```